# Django ManyToMany Field admin display highest value

Tags: python, django

I want to know how I can display the "highest value" from my ManyToMany Field in the admin. This is my `models.py` file:

```
class Personal(models.Model):
    lastname  = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    firstname = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    degree = models.ManyToManyField('Degree')
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.lastname

class Degree(models.Model):
    name_degree = models.CharField(verbose_name = 'Degree', max_length = 200, blank = False)
    rank = models.PositiveIntegerField(default = 0)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name_degree
```

In my backed, I have created different types of Degree's, all with a "ranking". In my case, the highest degree you can have is "Doctoral Degree", with a rank of "6". [image: Backed Admin List for Education]

So if a User is creating himself in "Personal" he will have the option to select all the Degree's he has achieved. But for my Personal list, I just to want to see the highest one, e.g. if the User selects "Bachelor's Degree" and "Master's Degree", the Personal list should only contain "Master's Degree", because 5 > 4.

Someone with an idea on how my `admin.py` file should look like?

```
class PersonalAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('lastname', 'firstname', ) # 'degree'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can annotate the `QuerySet` with the highest degree, and then define a method that will render that maximum:

```
from django.db.models import Max

class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['lastname', 'firstname', 'max_degree']

    def get_queryset(self, request):
        queryset = super().get_queryset(request).annotate(
            max_degree=Max('degree__rank')
        )

    def max_degree(self, obj):
        return obj.max_degree
```

Comment: Thank you for helping me I am sure this code works fine, but now when I try to open the admin list I get this error on my page ```Database error

Something’s wrong with your database installation. Make sure the appropriate database tables have been created, and make sure the database is readable by the appropriate user.```

Comment: @schuhesindbequem: did you create a database on your server, did you specified this correctly in the `settings.py`, and did you ran `makemigrations` and `migrate`.

Comment: I am using the normal Django settings, which looks like this ```DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
    }
}``` And yes, I did use migrations, deleted them and migrated again. What's weird is that I can normal add personal, it just wont show me on the page.

Comment: @schuhesindbequem: can your user read from the sqlite file. If there is no important data, it might help to remove the database file, and try again.

Comment: yes, I have removed the database file aswell. What exactly does that mean, because I think the superuser I create can read from the sqlite file if everything else works just fine. If I remove the code you gave me, the page doesn't give me this Database error and I can see all the personal created